# How to prevent primefaces schedule from switching to default month?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

Im currently facing a weird problem with scheduler behaviour. After sheduling new task for next month (or previous) scheduler's view changes to current month. Thats the behaviour i would like to prevent from happening.

Is there any flag that i can set to force him to stay on the same month as task that was scheduled ? Or does it require overriding defaults ?

Current code looks like this :

```
<p:schedule id="somecalendar" value="#{UI.scheduleModel}"
        widgetVar="calendar" locale="pl" axisFormat="H:mm" timeFormat="H:mm" timeZone="#{UI.timeZone}" >
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Solved by initialDate="#{UI.initialDate}" with correct format

Comment: You can also write (&accept) an answer, @Daniel.